# Reduce text inside a button HTML / CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my Javascript I receive a string of 16 characters:

```
0x67D77Ed8323bF9dA59addF3E34ccC6433c7f3B76
```

I show this as a button's value, however I would like to show only the first 3-4 digits and the last 2-3 with the dots in the middle, how can I do this?

Example:

```
0x67D77Ed8323bF9dA59addF3E34ccC6433c7f3B76
-> 0x67D ... 3B76
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

Comment: hey if you like an answer, you should mark it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) method to slice the string and then you can use anywhere you want.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("button");
const str = "0x67D77Ed8323bF9dA59addF3E34ccC6433c7f3B76";
const result = `${str.slice(0, 5)}...${str.slice(str.length - 4)}`;
console.log(result);

btn.textContent = result;
```

```html
<button></button>
```

Comment: thank so much, this is a great answer. I was also looking for an answer to this

Comment: What is printing on the browser when you are using `innerHTML` or Is there any error?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it, just pass your code to this function and it will slice the start and end 4 chars and return them with ... in between:

```
function codeShort(code){
    let a = code.slice(0, 4);
    let b = code.slice(-4);
    return `${a}..${b}`
}

console.log(codeShort('0x67D77Ed8323bF9dA59addF3E34ccC6433c7f3B76'));
//=>  "0x67..3B76"
```